Aluminum storm door paint wear
How do I repair this worn away paint on my aluminum door? Repaint?


What could possibly be the alternative? I don't understand your question.

Repaint, or remove the door and take it to the local powder coater.  Ask for a price to be stripped down and powder coated.  Compare that to the cost of a new door and the cost just to paint it. Then you can make an informed decision.
